# Use of sprays in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, riemannian-geometry

I have been reading *Fundamentals of Differential Geometry* by Serge Lang. In his treatment, the notion of *sprays* plays a central role. However, I rarely see this term in other books on the subject.

Although this is a soft question, I try to make clear my questions:

1. Is *spray* a somewhat out-dated notion?
2. What is the geometric meaning of sprays? (This name is suggestive but I don't have any intuition for it...)
3. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using sprays?
4. Can you suggest an alternative book whose treatment is similar to that of Lang's and which is modern and readable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lee's "Manifolds and Differential Geometry" is modern and handles sprays, but only within exercises.

Comment: Personally, I haven't used them much outside of some applications with subbundles of the double tangent bundle, but they play a fundamental roll in Finsler Geometry.  Cf. Connections, Sprays and Finsler Structures by Szilas, et. al.

Comment: The Legendre transform establishes a correspondence between curves in $M$ minimizing a Lagrangian and curves in $T^*M$  that are integral line of an Hamiltonian system on $T^*M$ induced by the Lagrangian.
Sprays are essentially the vector fields of these Hamiltonian systems. 

Since geodesics are curves minimizing the Length Lagrangian it makes sense to use sprays to talk about them.
Probably the advantages are more coordinate free  proofs or possibly some trick that allows to bypass the Levi-Civita connection.